# How to evaluate a nested preprocessor macro

Tags: c, gcc, macros, evaluation

let's say I want to select the behaviour of a certain preprocessor directive evaluating at compile time the concatenation of a constant string and the result of another macro.

```
#define CASE1 text1
#define CASE2 text2
#define CASE3 text3
#define SCENARIO 3
/** the following won't work - for examplification purposes only**/
#define FUNCTION CASE##SCENARIO

/** whenever I write FUNCTION, I expect to see text3 **/
```

I am having an hard time thinking of a viable solution, as the preprocessor is a one-pass beast. Is that even feasible ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's possible, you just need to add some extra layers of macros.  The key is that when you use the token-pasting operator `##`, the preprocessor will not expand its operands.  But, if you add another layer of macros, the preprocessor will expand those arguments.  For example:

```
#define CASE1 text1
#define CASE2 text2
#define CASE3 text3
#define SCENARIO 3

#define TOKENPASTE_HELPER(x, y) x ## y
#define TOKENPASTE(x, y) TOKENPASTE_HELPER(x, y)
#define FUNCTION TOKENPASTE(CASE, SCENARIO)
```

When the preprocessor expands `FUNCTION`, it expands `TOKENPASTE`.  When it expands `TOKENPASTE`, it expands its arugments (so `SCENARIO` gets replaced by `3`), since neither of its arguments are operands of the token-pasting operator.  Next, it expands `TOKENPASTE_HELPER`, which does the actual token pasting to make `CASE3`.  Finally, it expands the `CASE3` macro to get `text3`.

Comment: yeah, double level of indirection FTW. Thank you.